# Contraction: "it've"

Tags: grammaticality

I know that "could've" and similar contractions are common, but how would you rate "it've" as a contraction of "it have"? Acceptable? Horrible? Something else?

In case context matters: "Could it've come from the cave?"

Comment: What do your researches show about the acceptability of the candidate contraction  "it've", Ginette? English doesn't behave logically, and the fact that "Could it've come from the cave?" is probably the most felicitous way of committing what many Anglophones would say to print doesn't guarantee that such a transcription is acceptable. In popular fiction, you'd probably win rather than lose points. Elsewhere, ...

Comment: Normally _it_ would take _has_, but here the _have_ comes from being the infinitive following _would_, and there's no agreement with _it_ at all.

Comment: *It've* is an unambiguous rendition of an extremely common idiomatic usage.  Decide for yourself it's aesthetic merit ;)

Comment: "It've" is often a contraction of "it would have".  You do hear it used in this sense occasionally (probably most often as "it've been" -- "Oh, let me think ... it've been last year some time."), and you may even use it yourself from time to time, without realizing it.  You wouldn't normally see it in print, however, as it is not "official".

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth and Hot Licks indicate, the issue here involves representing in print what people say in real life. When a speaker pronounces the words "could it have"  rapidly and a bit slurringly, a writer might imitate it more accurately in print as "could it've" (or for that matter as "cuditv"). In this respect, "it've" is no more monstrous than "gimme" or "gonna" or "wannabe"—transliterations that have become quite common in informal writing. The acceptability of the spelling depends on how much non-dictionary-endorsed spelling the writer's milieu and audience permit.

Comment: I like it much better than *Could it **of** come from the cave?* which I suspect is how some folks would transcribe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to wrap my head around this, and eventually I realized that that's because "Could *it have* come from the cave?" sounds clunky to me anyway, so initially "it've" did as well. Either "Could it be from ..." or "Could it have emerged from ..." sound more natural to me.

To get back to your original question, does "Could it have emerged from ..." be contracted to "Could it've emerged from ..."? Even though it looks strange written down, it sounds perfectly good to me and the writing is unambiguous, as there's no other words "it've" could expand to here. So I'll say that it's an unusual but perfectly comprehensible construction.

Answer (score 3):

As a copywriter, my rule of thumb is, 'Does it sound natural?' i.e. the rule of [euphony](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphony).

'It've' sounds clunky to me, as does 'it'd' (it would). So I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Sound has very little, if anything, to do with it—this is about whether it’s acceptable **in written form**. _It’ve_ and _it’d_ may sound clunky to you when you think about it, but you would with almost complete certainty use both in normal speech without even noticing (and by “using both in speech”, I mean that you’d reduce the verbs to nondistinct syllables /ə(v/d)/ or remove them altogether, which is what the contracted spelling is meant to represent orthographically). _It’ve_ is a very uncommon and nonstandard contraction in writing, though, so it **looks** clunky, however it sounds.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds fine to me. In your example "Could it've come from the cave?", the subject of "could" is "it", and so if there were subject-verb number in the example it would have to be between "could" and "it". But "could" does not have a distinct singular-agreeing form.  "(ha)ve" in its position after the modal "could" cannot agree with the subject of the sentence.

(I didn't understand any of the comments -- maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: Could it've come from the cave? =Could it have come from the cave? Yes, it could have come from the cave. In fact, it could have been coming from the cave even as we were walking past the cave. I don't see any problem with subject-verb agreement here, just (as Dan says) an aesthetic choice.

Comment: I don’t understand this answer—what does subject–verb agreement have to do with whether or not an orthographic contraction of two words is common/standard/acceptable/horrible?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I was just guessing that  the question and comments above were prompted by some intuition that "it've" was odd because ordinarily a contracted auxiliary does agree with what it is contracted with.